# Text Overlapping Due to Height Percentage

Tags: html, css, height, percentage

I am currently working on a webpage. I wanted to add a background to the title that would resize with the size of the browser window. That meant  that I would have to add height to the div so I could change the height of the background with percent. When I added height to the div, the text of the webpage overlapped. Before adding height, the text was perfectly fine.  I hope this makes sense. Any help as to why the text overlapped or how to fix it would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML

```
<div>
      <p>
    <h1>Jonathan's Programming Notes!</h1>
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h2>Lesson 1</h2>
    </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>Blah</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>Content</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      Content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>Stuff</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <h2>Lesson 2</h2>
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>Words</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <h2>Lesson 3</h2>
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>Repetition</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h3>QWERTY</h3>
    </p>
    <p>
      QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY.
    </p>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
div {
height:100vh;}
h1 {
background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/RGD0");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 104%;
max-width: 85%;
height: 70%;
font-size: 42px;
font-weight: 700;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yq2wbax/).

Comment: not sure i understand the question - is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/9yq2wbax/6/

Comment: this maybe https://jsfiddle.net/9yq2wbax/8/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that all your divs were set to 100vh. I added a header div and a wrapper for your other divs and a class for it in your css. hope this makes sense

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://gdurl.com/RGD0");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 85% 70%;
  background-position: center top;
}
h1 {
  max-width: 85%;
  height: 70%;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>

    <h1>Jonathan's Programming Notes!</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <p>
        <h2>Lesson 1</h2>
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>Blah</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
          blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>Content</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          Content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
          content content content content content content content content content.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>Stuff</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
          stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        <h2>Lesson 2</h2>
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>Words</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
          words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>Text</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>
        <h2>Lesson 3</h2>
      </p>
      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>Repetition</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition
          Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition Repetition.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          <h3>QWERTY</h3>
        </p>
        <p>
          QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/9yq2wbax/8

Comment: Thanks! Your answer satisfied my question.

Comment: @Noobie123 great glad to hear it! welcome to Stack Overflow!